# Python and Azure-functions-core-tools

Tags: python, azure, npm, azure-functions

So let me get this straight. 
According the the [MS documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools), in order to run an Azure Function locally, with python, I have to install a JS package manager and use that to install a python package?

That doesn't seem right. Provided I am rather new, that doesn't seem like standard procedure. Has anyone installed this package and used it with python? I do also see that you can do it with Chocolatey.

Comment: Just use one method to install it it ok, then the func command can be use.

Comment: Any more problems?

Comment: Any process on this issue? If my answer could help you, you could accept it as the answer.

Comment: it does seem ... curious ... that tooling for python infrastructure is written in nodejs? whatever works works *shrug emojie*

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `npm` to install the `azure-functions-core-tools`, except this two ways, you could use the msi installer package file and the release zip file to configure it.

Go the **Azure Functions Core Tools**  [release page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases), download msi file of the version   you want, then just install it.

Or you could download the zip file, unzip it then set the folder path to your environment `Path`.

[image]

I test these two ways , both of them could work.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the method you can use, it doesn't matter.

Then you can use the func command on your computer and use it to create function app on local.

You can have a look of this doc, it describle clearly about how to work with python azure function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash